# SQL Server expression, string = 'test' not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean, expression

I am writing a SQL Server view, trying to calculate a field based on a string field.
This:

```
   SELECT        dbo.table2.field1 = 'Test' AS Expr25, dbo.table2.field1
   FROM            dbo.table1 INNER JOIN
                             dbo.table2 ON dbo.table1.ID = dbo.table2.ID
```

Gets automatically converted by Query designer to this:

```
SELECT        'dbo.table2.field1 = Test' AS Expr25, dbo.table2.field1
FROM            dbo.table1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.table2 ON dbo.table1.ID = dbo.table2.ID
```

The result I'm after should be a true/false value in the first column

Comment: I think you're going to have to show more of the code.   What you're describing isn't happening.  You're misinterpreting what you're seeing.

Comment: Do you mean `dbo.dimTable.myField+= N'Test'` instead of `dbo.dimTable.myField+ N'Test'`??

Comment: Are you talking about your query being mangled by a visual query designer or something?

Comment: Yes whenever I save the view it puts single quotes around it for some reason and then the output when I run it shows the actual code not the result of the code.

Comment: += did not work either. The underlying field is a varchar. Not sure why query designer has an issue with this. Pretty sure I'e done this sort of stuff before.

Comment: Can you describe the steps to reproduce the problem?  I bet you're trying to put a filter where a column goes.

Comment: Have added extra comments above. Someone had edited the post to highlight the code (which I appreciate) but the edit had missed out a crucial single quote which I've now corrected.

Comment: I agree with @TabAlleman here, what the OP is describing just isn't right. When typing `N'Text'` SQL Server would interpret it as the `nvarchar` value `Text`. The code you've supplied above doesn't run on it own; could you please provide the FULL SQL statement?

Comment: What do you mean  after it's been mangled by SQL Server? The service only runs the SQL you have provided. What's the SQL you're trying to run?

Comment: `SELECT dbo.dimTable.myField= N'Test'` isn't valid SQL. The designer is presumably trying to wrangle  it into something that is valid. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Ok I've written question above. I feel like I've done this sort of stuff before but perhaps I'm wrong and it's not valid. If not I'll have to use a union query.

Comment: Ah I see. SQL server doesn't have a boolean SQL data type. That syntax would work in other RDBMSs. You can use CASE or IIF

Comment: ^^^ SQL Server doesn't have boolean data type?

Comment: @LeeEverest internally it has one. E.g. EXISTS returns a boolean but this is not an allowable datatype for a column. The closest it has is BIT which is not a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no true or false you need to use case

```
    SELECT        case dbo.table2.field1 when 'Test' then 'true' else 'false' end 'true or false'
, dbo.table2.field1
    FROM            dbo.table1 INNER JOIN
                             dbo.table2 ON dbo.table1.ID = dbo.table2.ID
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I can now see how what I was trying to do above seemed confusing if SQL Server doesn't allow boolean expressions. I must have done them in some other RDBMS.    I can confirm CASE worked. Thank you all!